# Display problem when using RowEditor extension on an ExtJS GridPanel

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I'm using the RowEditor extension to edit a GridPanel. My ExtJS version is 3.3.0. I need some fields to be editable, others not no be edited at all and I do this by ignoring the `editor` property on those columns. The problem is that when an editor is not found, it is artificially generated in [`RowEditor.js`](http://trac.geoext.org/browser/ext/3.1.1/examples/ux/RowEditor.js?rev=2159) this way:

```
for(var i = 0, len = cm.getColumnCount(); i < len; i++){
        var c = cm.getColumnAt(i),
            ed = c.getEditor();
        if(!ed){
            ed = c.displayEditor || new Ext.form.DisplayField();
        }else{
            ed = ed.field;
        }
        //uninteresting code...
        this.insert(i, ed);
    }
```

The data is double displayed because of that, as you can see in the image below.

[image: Thy grid]

Is there a quick solution to get rid of that unnecessary text but still view the existing data on the grid? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to posit, no. Not without rewriting part of the plugin. Then again, you may be able to manually loop round the controls you don't want and hide them.. but that seems wrong.

I'd honestly just do without the rowEditor plugin. It's just as simple to have 'regular' editors (probably even same code you've used to specify editors thus far).

Then, again as you've already done, you just ignore the `editor` option of the columns you don't need.

If you want to have a more fancy look, you could try styling your selected row (`GetRowClass` in Ext.NET, similar in ExtJS? Or just override the CSS class of a selected row).